# How do you access match in a React-Redux container?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router, react-router-dom

Firstly, thank you to anyone who is reading this and is willing to help!

I'm trying to build a react-redux web app, and I'm having trouble accessing an id from the url in a container. The url looks like this: websitename.com/games/:game_id 
I need to access that :game_id so that I can use it in a redux action to make a call to my api, but I can't figure out how to access the usage of match. I get the following error when I try to compile:

./src/containers/GameDetails.js
  Line 9:19:  'match' is not defined  no-undef

My app is set up with the following structure: Main.js houses the routes:

```
import React from "react";
import {Switch, Route, withRouter, Redirect} from "react-router-dom";
import {connect} from "react-redux";
import Homepage from "../components/Homepage";
import AuthForm from "../components/AuthForm";
import {authUser} from "../store/actions/auth";
import {removeError} from "../store/actions/errors"
import withAuth from "../hocs/withAuth";
import GameForm from "./GameForm";
import GamePage from "../components/GamePage";

const Main = props => {
    const {authUser, errors, removeError, currentUser} = props;
    return (
        <div className="container">
            <Switch>
                <Route path="/" exact render={props => <Homepage currentUser={currentUser} {...props} /> } />
                <Route 
                    path="/signin" exact
                    render={props => {
                        return(
                            <AuthForm 
                                removeError={removeError}
                                errors={errors}
                                onAuth={authUser}
                                buttonText="Log in" 
                                heading="Welcome Back." 
                                {...props} 
                            />
                        )
                    }} />
                <Route 
                    path="/signup" exact
                    render={props => {
                        return(
                            <AuthForm
                                removeError={removeError}
                                errors={errors}
                                onAuth={authUser}
                                signUp
                                buttonText="Sign me up" 
                                heading="Join Weekly Matchup today." 
                                {...props} 
                            />
                        )
                    }} 
                />
                <Route 
                    path="/games/new" exact
                    component={withAuth(GameForm)}
                />
                <Route
                    path="/games/:game_id" 
                    render={props => {
                        return(
                            <GamePage 
                                currentUser={currentUser}
                                {...props} 
                            />
                        )
                    }}
                />
                <Redirect to="/" />
            </Switch>
        </div>
    )
}

function mapStateToProps(state){
    return {
        currentUser: state.currentUser,
        errors: state.errors
    };
}

export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps, {authUser, removeError})(Main));
```

GamePage.js is a component that has the GameDetails container in it:

```
import React from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import GameDetails from "../containers/GameDetails";

const GamePage = ({ currentUser }) => {


    if (!currentUser.isAuthenticated) {
        return (
            <div className="home-hero">
                <h1>You must sign in or sign up in order to vote for matchups and view comments.</h1>
            </div>
        );
    }
    return (
        <div>
            <div className="home-hero">
                <GameDetails />
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default GamePage;
```

And GameDetails.js is where I'm trying to get the id from the url to use in my redux action:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { getGameDetails } from "../store/actions/games";

class GameDetails extends Component {

    componentDidMount() {
        const game_id = match.params.game_id;
        this.props.getGameDetails(game_id);
    }
    render() {
        const { match, game } = this.props;

        return (
            <div className="home-hero">
                <div className="offset-1 col-sm-10">
                        <h4>You are viewing the Game Page for game.title</h4>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        game: state.game
    };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { getGameDetails })(
    GameDetails
);
```

I'm still very new to react and redux, so I appreciate any help you can offer.
Thank you for your time and patience!

Comment: Is `match` passed as a prop to `GameDetails`?

Comment: I guess not. How...do I do that? I'm sorry for such a basic question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this in GameDetails.js and GamePage.js

```
import React from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import GameDetails from "../containers/GameDetails";

const GamePage = ({ currentUser, ...props }) => {


if (!currentUser.isAuthenticated) {
    return (
        <div className="home-hero">
            <h1>You must sign in or sign up in order to vote for matchups and view comments.</h1>
        </div>
    );
}
return (
    <div>
        <div className="home-hero">
            <GameDetails {...props} />
        </div>
    </div>
)
}

export default GamePage;

import React, { Component } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { getGameDetails } from "../store/actions/games";

class GameDetails extends Component {

componentDidMount() {
    const {game_id}= this.props.match.params.game_id;
    this.props.getGameDetails(game_id);
}
render() {
    const { match, game } = this.props;

    return (
        <div className="home-hero">
            <div className="offset-1 col-sm-10">
                    <h4>You are viewing the Game Page for game.title</h4>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
return {
    game: state.game
};
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { getGameDetails })(
GameDetails
);
```

Comment: I tried what you suggested and it gives me this error:
Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
See https://fb(dot here, but it won't let me put a shortened url in the comments)me/react-invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.

Comment: Thank you so much! It seems to be working now: I can see that match and game_id are defined in the react dev-tools. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you use you exported component same thing like
`<Route path="/games/:game_id" component={GameDetails} />`
`mapStateToProps` get 2 arguments `state`, and `ownProps`.

```
function mapStateToProps(state, ownProps) {
    const { match: { params: { game_id } } } = ownProps; // you able to use game_id inside mapStateToProps
    return ({ game: state.game });
}
```

Comment: Ah, I see, I have it set up like this right now. I have a Main.js container that holds my Route to the GamePage.js component which has the GameDetails.js container. I'll edit the original post to reflect that.

Comment: I have 2 solutions for you.
1. wrap withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Component)).
2. get rest props from `GamePage` and pass it to `GameDetails `

Answer (score 0):

1 solution

```js
import React from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import GameDetails from "../containers/GameDetails";

const GamePage = ({ currentUser, ...routeProps }) => {


    if (!currentUser.isAuthenticated) {
        return (
            <div className="home-hero">
                <h1>You must sign in or sign up in order to vote for matchups and view comments.</h1>
            </div>
        );
    }
    return (
        <div>
            <div className="home-hero">
                <GameDetails {...routeProps} />
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default GamePage;
```

2 solution

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { Link, withRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import { getGameDetails } from "../store/actions/games";

class GameDetails extends Component {

    componentDidMount() {
        const game_id = match.params.game_id;
        this.props.getGameDetails(game_id);
    }
    render() {
        const { match, game } = this.props;

        return (
            <div className="home-hero">
                <div className="offset-1 col-sm-10">
                        <h4>You are viewing the Game Page for game.title</h4>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        game: state.game
    };
}

export default withRouter(
  connect(mapStateToProps, { getGameDetails })(GameDetails)
);
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions, but unfortunately neither of them work. Do I need an additional file like a Higher Order Component for these solutions to work?

Comment: No. Could you try to `connect(mapStateToProps, { getGameDetails }, null, { pure: false })(GameDetails)`?